# documenting dataset with roxygen2

Tags: r, packaging, roxygen2, rd

I'm trying to document some datasets in an R package using roxygen2. Considering just one of these:

- I have `mypkg/data/CpG.human.GRCh37.RDa`
- which contains an object called `CpG.human.GRCh37`
- and a file called: `mypkg/R/cpg-data.R`, which contains:

  ```
  #' @name CpG.human.GRCh37
  #' @title CpG islands - human - genome build: GRCh37/hg19
  #' @description This data set list the genomic locations of human CpG islands,
  #' with coordinates based on the GRCh37 / hg19 genome build.
  #' @docType data
  #' @usage CpG.human.GRCh37
  #' @format a \code{RangedData} instance, 1 row per CpG island.
  #' @source UCSC Table Browser
  #' @author Mark Cowley, 2012-03-05
  #' @export
  NULL
  ```

When I roxygenize, this gets created `mypkg/man/CpG.human.GRCh37.Rd`, containing:

```
    \docType{data}
    \name{CpG.human.GRCh37}
    \alias{CpG.human.GRCh37}
    \title{CpG islands - human - genome build: GRCh37/hg19}
    \format{a \code{RangedData} instance, 1 row per CpG island.}
    \source{
      UCSC Table Browser
    }
    \description{
      This data set list the genomic locations of human CpG
      islands, with coordinates based on the GRCh37 / hg19
      genome build.
    }
    \author{
      Mark Cowley, 2012-03-05
    }
    \usage{CpG.human.GRCh37}
    \keyword{datasets}
```

and `export(CpG.human.GRCh37)` gets added the `NAMESPACE` file.

but when I `R CMD CHECK` I get:

```
...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: CpG.human.GRCh37
Error: loading failed
...
```

Nowhere have I told R where to find this dataset, though I would assume that the `mypkg/data/<name>.RDa` would be a good first guess.
Any hints would be awesome.

If Hadley's watching, I notice that an \usage section is not created and the @usage directive is ignored.

i'm using roxygen-2.2.2, on R 2.13.1

Comment: I'm not sure that the `@export` directive is used for data sets. Try removing this.

Comment: you should not export the data object

Comment: thanks guys. this required 2 fixes (1) as per Writing R extensions 1.5.1, save the objects as .rda (not .RDa); and (2) remove the @export

Comment: @mjc Kindly post your comment as an answer and mark it answered to close off this question.

Comment: @mjc, please post an answer and accept it so that this question does not show up an unanswered.

Answer (score 17):

This required 2 fixes:

1. As explained in [Writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) 1.1.5, [Data in packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages), save the objects as `.rda` instead of `.RDa`
2. remove `@export` from the Roxygen