# Exporting data in Roxygen2 so that they are available without requiring data()

Tags: r, roxygen2, rd

After reading questions such as [this SO question on documenting a data set with Roxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561684/documenting-dataset-with-roxygen2) I have managed to document a dataset (which I will refer to as `cells`) and it now appears in the list generated by `data(package="mypackage")` and is loaded if I run the command `data(cells)`. After this, `cells` will appear when `ls()` is run.

However, in many packages the data is immediately available without requiring a `data()` call. Also, the data names do not appear when `ls()` is run. An example is the `baseball` data set that comes with `plyr`. I have looked at the source for `plyr` and I cannot see how this is done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `DESCRIPTION` file of your package make sure that there is a field called `LazyData` that is set to `TRUE`.

From the "Writing R Extensions" guide:

> The ‘data’ subdirectory is for data files, either to be made available
>   via lazy-loading or for loading using data(). (The choice is made by
>   the ‘LazyData’ field in the ‘DESCRIPTION’ file: the default is not to
>   do so.)

I think the exact syntax changed with R version 2.14; before that it was LazyLoad not LazyData.

Comment: Thanks! I was almost there. I had just entered 'true'. Either it's case sensitive, or I didn't rebuild properly.